# What does 'this' refer to in this peace of the code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, set, prototype

I am reading a code like below:

```
export abstract class CustomError extends Error {
  abstract statusCode: number;

  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);

    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);

  }

  abstract serializeErrors(): { message: string; field?: string }[];
}
```

I can't understand what does `this` refer to? I think in this case `this` should be equal to `CustomError`, and if so, this expression would be meaning less to me:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
```

Because it's like:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, this.prototype);
```

And it assigns the class's prototype to an object of same class's prototype that I can't understand the reason? I mean `this` should have this prototype itself by default, shouldn't it?

Comment: `this` refers to the object you want to change the prototype. `CustomError` is a class, not an object.

Comment: Here 'this' referred as the instance of class itself. Refer this article for more info on 'this'  link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-this-keyword-binding-rules/#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20the%20this%20keyword,when%20we%20invoke%20a%20method.

Comment: @jabaa: Could you explain more or write it as an answer with examples?

Comment: An object is an instance of a class: `const obj = new CustomError()`. `this` refers to `obj`, not to `CustomError`. A class has a prototype and an object has also a prototype. Both prototypes are usually different. In this code, the constructor sets the prototype of the class as the prototype of the object.

Comment: @jabaa: So why it isn't like `Object.setPrototypeOf(this.prototype , CustomError.prototype);` ?

Comment: That's answered in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). The first argument is the _"object which is to have its prototype set"_ and the second argument is the _"object's new prototype (an object or `null`)"_.

Answer (score -1):

this reffers to the variable itself. If I made a class,

```
class thing{
         constructor() {console.log(this)}
}
new thing();
```

"this" reffers to the class.

Answer (score -3):

Just like it says in the code

```
 Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
```

this represents or refers to an object in javascript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).